# Android. onActivityResult not triggered inside fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I'm starting an `Activity` for result inside a `Fragment`. But `onActivityResult()` inside my `Fragment` is not triggered. Debugging the class `FragmentActivity`, I see that `onActivityResult()` is triggered. Whan can happen wrong?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SomeClass.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Can you post the code in which you are starting the `Activity` for result?

Comment: This question is already asked you can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)